# Azure assign group and device to script using Graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, intune

I am trying to assign groups and devices to a PowerShell script in Microsoft Intune using the following POST request:
URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/deviceManagementScripts/%7Bid%7D/Assign

Body:
`{`
`"deviceManagementScriptGroupAssignments": [`
`{`
`"@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.deviceManagementScriptGroupAssignment",`
`"id": "{ScriptId:GroupId}",`
`"targetGroupId": "{GroupId}"`
`}`
`],`
`"deviceManagementScriptAssignments": [`
`{`
`"@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.deviceManagementScriptAssignment",`
`"id": "{ScriptID:DeviceID}",`
`"target": {`
`"@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.allDevicesAssignmentTarget",`
`"deviceAndAppManagementAssignmentFilterId": null,`
`"deviceAndAppManagementAssignmentFilterType": "none"`
`}`
`}`
`]`
`}`

However, I am getting a 400 error with the following message:

`"{ "_version": 3, "Message": "An error has occurred - Operation ID (for customer support): 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 - Activity ID: 615c3437-bd99-2193-9d4b-d9a61deb0340 - Url: https://fef.amsua0102.manage.microsoft.com/DeviceFE/StatelessDeviceFEService/deviceManagement/deviceManagementScripts('{id}')/microsoft.management.services.api.assign?api-version=5022-11-08", "CustomApiErrorPhrase": "", "RetryAfter": null, "ErrorSourceService": "", "HttpHeaders": "{}"}"`

I base on this document of Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-shared-devicemanagementscript-assign?view=graph-rest-beta

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment.***

Received the same error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "{\"ErrorCode\":\"Forbidden\",\"Message\":\"{\\  \\\"_version\\\": 3,\\  \\\"Message\\\": \\\"An error has occurred - Operation ID (for customer support): xxxx –

}
```

[image]

When I followed the url in the error and queried, I got that the api version is not supported.

[image]

Make sure the authorization header is given with bearer token which has proper permissions to work with intune and device management

[image]

Omit the parameter @odata.type in the post request body.

```
{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.deviceManagementScript",
    …
    "runAs32Bit": true
}
```

[image]

Make sure you have `DeviceManagementConfiguration.ReadWrite.All`  Application and delegated permissions.

[image]

**`Note that  Intune requires an active Intune license for the tenant.`**